# Adding transitions to a Javascript Show/Hide Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help adding transitions to this show/hide js code, the code works for me but I'm struggling with getting these to show/hide smoothly

Any transition will do really, as long as it points me in the direction of getting transitions on both divs that would be perfect

```js
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {

                if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}
```

```css
#Div2 {
  display: none;
}
a{cursor: pointer; font-weight: 600;}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2">Div 2</div>

<a id="Button1" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();">hide</a>
```

Comment: Is using display necessary? Can we use visibility instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is using `visibility: hidden` (and `visible`) combined with `transition` and `optical` attribute.

You can check on the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKZmVG)

Answer (score 1):

When you set `display: none` you can also add `opacity: 0` for the div that is supposed to be hidden.

Then you set `opacity: 1` for the div that is supposed to be shown.

Finally, add `transition: 0.2s ease-in-out` to both of them and you should see a smooth transition when it gets hidden and shown. 0.2s means seconds, so change that to something you like.

EDIT:

So according to Gezzasas comment it won't work with the style attribute. So I've removed that and changed your code so it will show smooth transitions.

[You can check the code by clicking here (codepen).](https://codepen.io/danielbarillo/pen/ERGmaa)

Comment: This will not work. `display: none;` will always instantly show and hide because it is either displaying or not.

Comment: why don't you go for jquery ?

Comment: Any way you could put this in could perhaps @AdeshKumar

Comment: @ZUH. I've updated my answer to show how it would work with my solution. No jQuery needed.

Comment: When going the simple route of just changing opacity, you might also want to set `user-select:none;pointer-events:none;` when opacity is `0`

Comment: @MstrQKN hey, just realised that when this is put alongside other elements the "position:absolute" causes the div to display over other content, would there be another replacement for that?